# can hector_slam be used to create 3D models?

Tags: ros, lidar, 3d-slam, hector-slam, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Does hector_slam create only 2D maps or can it be used to created 3D models as well?
My data comes from a Velodyne LiDAR and I need to create a 3D model of the object that is being scanned. I am looking for the right tool to use and was not sure if hector_slam could create 3D models. If it can't and you can recommend something else, please do so :)
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226823/can-hector_slam-be-used-to-create-3d-models?/) by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hector_slam performs localization only in 2D, but if you combine that information with IMU data (for roll and pitch) and additional data about the z position (from prior knowledge, odometry or other sensors), it can be used for 3D mapping. This approach is used for building a 3D octomap-based map via mapping with known poses using a RGB-D sensor with our autonomous USAR robots as [visible in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgNFeDH3qFk).

Depending on your accuracy requirements, sensor motion and scale of environment other solutions might be worth a look. See for instance [this recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlAArM_6N-I) made using a Velodyne HDL-64e. [ethzasl_icp_mapping](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping) also uses libpointmatcher and you could try that.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on 2016-02-17**:
Thank you Stefan. It is not immediately clear from the video the quality of the 3D model, the resolution, etc. but I will look into libpointmatcher and ethzasl_icp_mapping. I am specifically interested in mounting VLP-16 on a drone and scanning a small building with a couple cm or better resolution.

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2016-02-29**:
Hi, I'm doing something similar as you are up to. I first tried using lpm/ethzasl_icp_mapping but was disappointed by the high percentage of points that you have to filter out to get it running in realtime. I found configuring it quite hard. Please let me know if you're better at tweaking params :)

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2016-02-29**:
Also, I implemented a point to plane algo that doesnt rely on kd trees for surface normal approximation and src/tar point association. It seems to be *a_lot* faster (>20iter, 100%pts) than lpm and doesnt deteriorate with map size . I'll try to write up the approach and release code end of next month

**Comment by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on 2016-03-02**:
@jodafo, I haven't had a chance to try it yet. But please let me know of your results :)

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-03-03**:
Our team is also working on 3D SLAM by modifying some existing 2D SLAM algorithm such as hector_slam, gmapping and MRPT icp-SLAM. We are not sure whether we can successfully modify hector_slam because it seems hard to add IMU data to it, neither is gmapping.
Hope to see any of your progress :)

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-04-10**:
Hi Clack, how much work have you done ? have you been successful in modifying hector_slam to get a 3D SLAM ?

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-04-10**:
We've mainly focused on building a 2D SLAM system recently. However one of our teammates planned to convert 2D point cloud to 3D using data obtained by IMU. He will have this done in maybe one month. I will inform you as soon as we have a progress. And we are also curious about your idea :)

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-04-10**:
I mean the 3D point clouds are based on 2D ones obtained by the laser scanner. And IMU data are used to build a transform relationship between 2D and 3D.

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-06-22**:
clack, do you have any updates? that is exactly what I am trying to do

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-06-24**:
We recently encountered problems with 3D point clouds distortion caused by IMU and we are looking for papers and other resources to figure out how to fix that. If we had this done we will inform you ASAP :)

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-06-24**:
Thank you. Do you have any hints of things I could look into to try to get started? I have a 2D LaserScan working with octomap and I have ordered the Razor 9DOF IMU. I'm wondering if the Third dimension is integrated automatically by ROS once I have the IMU node?

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-06-24**:
I think so, the standard IMU message type in ROS is 3 dimensional, that is, the node will output 3D points which represents the pose of the IMU. But if you want to use those messages to convert your 2D LIDAR points to 3D, you need to write a new node, which is exactly our group is working at.

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-06-28**:
I look forward to hearing about your progress :)

**Comment by [ricot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30228/ricot/) on 2017-05-02**:
Hello, I am new to ROS and trying to do the exact same thing. @Clack what were the main hurdles you went through and were you able to get the 3d points out of the 2d Lidar ? Are there guidelines somewhere that I could follow and/or is your code public ?

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2017-05-02**:
Hello, ricot. Actually I'm not working on this topic any more. However one of the members in our lab is now using a kind of framework called LOAM to build a 3D map using LiDAR and IMU. The performance is quite impressive. Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i was successful in generating a 3D map of the indoor environments (somewhat rough). I have used hector_localization and hector_mapping for localizing my robot in a 3D environment and octomapps for generating the maps. hector_localization is provided with imu messages and poseupdate topic from the hector_mapping node. Thanks to Stefan for providing the file which is linked in this answer

http://answers.ros.org/question/224015/hi-everyone-i-am-new-to-ros-and-i-want-to-make-a-3d-map-using-a-lidar-and-a-kinect-is-it-possible/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REdjzbwmdtM

---

Originally posted by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) with karma: 53 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-06-27**:
Can you please email me at ateator@jhfletcher.com ? I am interested in a setup much like yours and would like to see your cose / ask you questions.

**Comment by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on 2016-06-27**:
@ateator, if possible, can you keep this correspondence public so that others can benefit from it too? ;)
@hashim, did you use an IMU in your setup?

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-06-28**:
yes i have used imu in the setup, but i am thinking of writing a blog or something like this on it. first see the video, there are some errors but they can be removed using a better hardware

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-29**:
I've generated fairly accurate 3D maps of indoor environments using hector_mapping, hector_imu_attitude_to_tf, and octomap_server using a laser scanner, ultrasonic range finder for altitude, and an IMU for orientation.

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-06-29**:
Well, icehawk, is there any way we could get copies of some of your files? Possibly over email?

**Comment by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on 2016-06-29**:
@icehawk101, how do you use a range finder for measuring altitude? And yes, it would be great to see the maps you were able to generate.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-29**:
I have the ulrasonic sensor facing down to determine the range between the prototype and the ground, then I built a node that takes the pose estimate from hector_mapping, adds the height as a z value for the pose, then publishes a transform from base_footprint->base_stabilized

**Comment by [kumar12](https://answers.ros.org/users/32362/kumar12/) on 2017-10-23**:
I am trying to do a similar setup, can you guide me on how to interface hector_slam with octomap 3D?